# Different anchor point for EPSG:3857 coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, proj4js

I have a couple of points in the `EPSG:3857` CRS. These points are centered on `0, 0`, which is the center of a map. I can convert these points to `EPSG:4326` in Javascript with the `proj4js` library using this code:

```js
function calcLngLat(x, y) {
    // convert from kilometers to meters
    x = x * 1000;
    y = y * 1000;

    // convert from 3857 to 4326
    var latLng4326 = proj4('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326', [x, y]);

    var lng = latLng4326[1];
    var lat = latLng4326[0];

    return [lng, lat]
}

// returns [-0.43657700341632283, 0.733923587125649]
calcLngLat(81.7, -48.6);
```

(here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70ezwrLt/) of that code)

As you can see by the return values, the resulting `lat, lng` points are clearly centered around `0, 0`, because the input `x, y` values also are.

How can I get the return values to **not** be centered, or anchored, on `0, 0`? Let's say I want them to be anchored on `-97, 35` (lng, lat)? That would make the return values for the above function be very close to those two anchor coordinates, not `0, 0`. I hope you understand what I'm saying.

Comment: Both Web Mercator and GCS_WGS_1984 have an origin at the intersection of the Prime Meridian with the Equator.  Besides adding 35 to lat and subtracting 97 from lon, what are you expecting to accomplish?

Comment: I tried adding 35 to the converted lat and subtracting 97 from the converted lng, but it gave me incorrect values. I am using this function to convert hundreds of points, that will all form a shape on a map. Using the method you just suggested, it gave me a warped shape, leading me to assume there was a more nuanced way to do it.

Comment: The operation itself makes no sense, so it's not surprising that it doesn't work (for whatever "work" means). You're treating coordinates as if they have no value, which is not generally how geographic data is processed. Note that the poles are infinitely far from the Equator in Web Mercator, so the starting point makes a significant difference in the ending point.